# Is my hardware up to the task of 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I attempted to install 14.04.5 LTS yesterday on my laptop and as it got to the splash screen I was hopeful, however, the little orange dots froze on 3 and just stayed there. Eventually, my laptop shut itself off.

I tried Xubuntu and Lubuntu 14.04 to the same end.

I'm now working with Ubuntu 12.04.5 64bit and it's working well but obviously LTS is running out in a few months so I'd like to upgrade.

My system specs are as follows:

```
Asus X553M laptop 64 bit,
Intel Celeron N2840 @ 2.16ghz,
2 500Gb hard drives, one of which hosts Windows 10,
Intel HD Graphics (it doesn't specify which version),
8 gigs of RAM.
```

Unfortunately UEFI but I have secure boot and fast start up turned off and Launch CSM enabled.

I've used Win32diskimager, rufus and UUI to make the live USB.

Windows 10 runs smoothly so I can't understand why Ubuntu won't.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you would like to run 14.04 instead of 16.04 which is the new LTS? As for your question - the hardware seems more than capable of running both 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: Well, I initially tried 16.04 and had the same problem, frozen at the splash screen then laptop shuts down.

Comment: If Windows is UEFI, you want Ubuntu in UEFI and only 64 bit verison is 64 bit except for a few Atom processors that are 64 bit but 32bit UEFI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely have a read at these. Quick question though, would upgrading through Ubuntu help or do you not think it would work?

Comment: OK, having read through those pages on UEFI, I think it might be the problem that I had "Launch  CSM" ie Legacy mode turned on and it's complicated things.  Not sure though if I should clean install or upgrade from inside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop is shutting off because it's overheating, and the BIOS shuts it down to protect the hardware.

Put your BIOS *CSM/legacy boot* setting back to UEFI, and then **install** Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode, like Windows 10.

I prefer recommending a Ubuntu fresh **install** be done from a **Ubuntu Live DVD**, not a USB flash drive. It's much more reliable.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I think my problems are solved.